# Search button in toolbar for fragment is not displaying keyboard

Tags: android, search, toolbar

I have multiple fragments in an activity where I want a search button in the toolbar. In one of my fragments this all successfully works but when I copied the exact same code into my other two fragments they aren't functioning properly.

When I click the search button on the working fragment, the keyboard pops up and I can start entering text. But on the other two fragments when I press on the search button icon, it slides to the left and then I need to press it again for it to work. Anyone know how I can fix this?

[image]
[image]

```
    @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView sv = new SearchView(((Home) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(item, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW | MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, sv);
    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            list.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < mainList.size(); i++) {
                if (mainList.get(i).getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(newText.toLowerCase(), 0) || mainList.get(i).getAddress().toLowerCase().startsWith(newText.toLowerCase())) {
                    list.add(mainList.get(i));
                }
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return false;
        }
    });

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.action_search:
        getActivity().onSearchRequested();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to define searchView in menu item.

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
      android:title="@string/search"
      app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
      app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always" />
```

Comment: I tried that already, in my search menu item I have

`<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:appcompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        appcompat:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        appcompat:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>`

Comment: it works for me. It could be an issue with styles, do you use any custom styles for searchView?

Comment: I used a custom theme for the app but not for the searchview

Answer (score 0):

Hey i have same issue and i found solution for it. it may be because of you are giving a whole menu for search view. so when you click first time on search icon that full menu gets load and then you again click on search icon and then search view gets open.

Try below code

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) 
{
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.searchview, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search);
    SearchView sv = (SearchView) item.getActionView(); 
    if (sv != null){
        sv.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        sv.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

**searchview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_search"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Search"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="true"/>
</menu>
```

And make sure you import **android.support.v7.widget.SearchView** otherwise it will give error in casting.

Hope it will help.